# Jmockit: Mocking a @EJB

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng, jmockit

I googled for solutions but to no avail.

```
public class Bean {
    @EJB
    private Session session;

    public String register(String a, String b, String c) {
        return session.create(a, b, c).toString();
    }
```

and i have a test class

```
@Test
public void testRegister(String a, String b, String c) {

    new MockUp<Bean>() {         
        @Mocked Session session; 
    };

    System.out.println("session: "+ session);
    Bean bean = new Bean ();
    System.out.println("apiService: "+ bean);
    System.out.println("bean.register: "+ bean.register("a", "b", "c"));

}
```

Im trying a few different ways for instanitating/injecting the EJB. But it all returned null. How do you inject the @EJB Session for testing of register method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i found out that @Injectable in the test class does the job. Tried @Mocked and @Cascading, but didnt work out well

```
@Injectable private Session session;
```